# How can I detect the day of the week and the time, and then display data in a tableview based on the current day and time?

Tags: iphone, database, datetime

I have a list of data that is a schedule.  Each item has a time that it takes place in.  I want to detect the current day and time and then display what items are available during that time.  All I really know is how to get todays date and time and that I need to create a method to look in my data at what is currently "playing".  Any suggestions?

Comment: OP said: `How can I detect the day of the week and the time` and OP said: `All I really know is how to get todays date and time`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assuming that your schedule items are stored in an `NSArray` called `scheduleItems` and that these items have a `date` property, you could filter them with a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", 
                            [NSDate date]];
NSArray *todaysItems = [scheduleItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The problem is that this will give you every item where its date is exactly now.  You probably want to compare the date in a range:

```
NSDate *today = ...;
NSDate *tomorrow = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date BETWEEN %@",
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:today, tomorrow,nil]];
NSArray *todaysItems = [scheduleItems fileteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

*Note: this is not tested.*